# PHP My Themes download page

Tags: php

When my users purchase a 'theme', after purchase is done, I add the theme to the theme_purchases MySQL table.

Like this:

**PurchaseID -- UserID -- Theme Id**

**1 -- 44 -- 4**

There's a page named mythemes.php that will show all of the themes this user have purchased.
The user will be able to download the theme by clicking the button "Download".

And I want to handle the downloads like in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15951217/1761494

In my case (With the user & his own themes), do I need to use Tokens (According to the answer I posted above).

Are there any other solutions for having a download page, protecting the download link ? use can download his theme any time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that i understand your question as well. But, if you want to protect the theme file by hiding their real folder, maybe this could be good way:
If the file is a zip, you just write a download php file, give the theme id with GET method. In download file you can check that it has right to download it, if yes, you send a header and the file, maybe like this:

```
$filename = "thiszip.zip"; 
header('Content-type: application/zip'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"'); 
header("Content-length: " . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: Yes, because the file's real path has never appeared.

Comment: Can you explain how does it downloads the file? it only reads the file I think.